# Laravel Model Factories and Eloquent; setting dates

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-5

So I have an `App\Post` model in my app, defined as follows:

```
namespace App;
class Post extends Model 
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'published_at', 'deleted_at'];
    // etc...
}
```

I created a model factory, a nice new feature as of Laravel 5.1 to define the blueprint of a `Post` as follows:

```
$factory->define('App\Post', function($faker) {
    return [
    'title'     => $faker->sentence,
    'content'   => $faker->paragraph,
    'published_at' => $faker->dateTimeThisMonth(),
    ];
});
```

As we can see I set the `published_at` field to be a random date this month, as generated by the `Faker` instance. The method used returns an instance of `DateTime`.

However when I generate some `Post`s I find the `published_at` field to be null, suggesting that the `DateTime` instance is not being correctly interpreted.

I found that if I changed that line to:

```
'published_at' => Carbon::instance($faker->dateTimeThisMonth())->toDateTimeString(),
```

which essentially converts the `DateTime` to a `Carbon` and then outputs a date-time string e.g. `"2015-06-15 13:44:23"`, it works correctly.

Is this really the best way to define faker dates in model factories? I would've thought the fact that I defined `published_at` in the `$dates` array Laravel would interpret the `DateTime` (or `Carbon`) instance and save it without me having to provide a string.

**Edit**

I'm finding that this is also not working for simple Eloquent creates:

E.g. if I run

```
App\Post::create([
    'title' => $title,
    'content' => $faker->paragraph(4),      
    'published_at' => new Carbon,
    'created_at' => Carbon::parse('2015-06-16')
]);
```

The `published_at` and `created_at` field are still null. Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen a couple of Laracasts videos and Jeffrey always uses Carbon inside factories. So, I'd say that's the best way

Answer (score 7):

Since Faker is returning a DateTime-Object which isn't representing a date-string like mysql likes it (`Y-m-d H:i:s`) the field will be set to null.

You should however be able to access the objects property `date` to get the correct string like this:

```
$faker->dateTimeThisMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

This should return a date like this `string '2015-06-19 13:07:07' (length=19)`

Comment: Yes, essentially that's what I'm doing, but I just use the Carbon method to generate the string. Essentially what I want is to be able to set a DateTime or Carbon instance as a date and have eloquent save it in the database. This is described [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) but I'm not getting this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` dates inside model factories without a problem.

In order to make it work please add the `published_at` and `created_at` to the `$fillable` property.

Then it should work fine.